# How can I transform a matrix so that I can plot using ggplot

Tags: r, matrix, plot, ggplot2

I have a matrix in R that I can plot using matplot however it is hard to customize the plot. I would like to plot using the R package ggplot however it will not work using a matrix. I am not sure what transformations are required of the matrix to allow the data to work with ggplot.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could coerce to a dataframe with as.data.frame, then add column names with the colnames argument.

Comment: Have you tried as.data.frame() function to transform?

Comment: a reproducible example will help a lot.  You can try (1) `as.data.frame.table()` (2) `reshape2::melt()`

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the matrix to a data frame

```
    mat  = cbind(index = seq(1:10), price=7+rnorm(10))
    df = as.data.frame(mat)
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = index, y = price))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reshape2::melt as mentioned in the comment. Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(ggplot2)
# generating a random matrix
numbers <- sample(c(1:100), 100, replace = T)
data <- matrix( numbers, ncol=10)
rownames(data) <- paste0("row-", seq(1,10))
colnames(data) <- paste0("col-", seq(1,10))
data # a matix
#  converting to a ggplot dataframe
df <- reshape2::melt(data, c("row", "col"), value.name = "values")
head(df)
# plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x = col, y = values)) + geom_boxplot() #group by columns
ggplot(df, aes(x = row, y = values)) + geom_boxplot() #group by rows
```